# D3.js: Calculating the y Scale from a Stack function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want a ‘mirrored’ bar chart (i.e. one that looks like a sound wave) and have come up with the following using the d3 [stack generator](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stack) and a linear y scale:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

const WIDTH = 300;
const HEIGHT = 300;

const LIMIT = 4;

const container = d3.select("svg").append("g");

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    index: i,
    value: Math.random() * LIMIT
  });
}

var stack = d3
  .stack()
  .keys(["value"])
  .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
  .offset(d3.stackOffsetSilhouette);

var series = stack(data);

var xScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([0, WIDTH])
  .domain([0, data.length]);

var yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([HEIGHT, 0])
  .domain([0, LIMIT / 2]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

container
  .selectAll(".bar")
  .data(series[0])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", d => {
    return xScale(d.data.index);
  })
  .attr("y", d => {
    return yScale(d[0]) / 2 - HEIGHT / 2;
  })
  .attr("width", WIDTH / series[0].length)
  .attr("height", d => yScale(d[1]));
```

However, I feel like I’ve hacked the calculations for both the y scale domain and for positioning the blocks.

For the domain I currently use 0 to the data's `upper limit / 2`.

For my y position I use `yScale(d[0]) / 2 - HEIGHT / 2;` despite the height being directly based off the scale i.e. `d => yScale(d[1])`.

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the way the stack function calculates values has changed since D3 v2, and therefore I had to do two things to achieve this in a nicer way.

I switched my y scale domain to be the extents of the data and then translated by `-0.5 * HEIGHT`

I modified my calculation for the y position and height:

```
.attr('y', d => yScale(d[1]))
.attr('height', d => yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]));
```